# I want the " Add gift options" and "Add gift options for the Entire Order" checked by default

Tags: magento-1.9, gift-card

In the order process - when customers come up to the "Do you have any gift items in your order?" section of the order --) they have to click the check-mark into " Add gift options." first and then - ANOTHER check-mark into "Add gift options for the Entire Order" under the "Gift Options for the Entire Order." section.

**This makes no sense for us because all of our customers will have to leave a Message card so this clicking and clicking again to put 2 check-marks in there is really unnecessary!**

Any ideas on how to make it show up by default without the need to put any check-marks anywhere?

*Magento 1.9.1.0
just installed the Porto Theme #11*

---

**Updated on March 22nd, 2019:**

I am trying to set this up on Magento 1.9.4 but I don't have any luck. I have modified both the

```
/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/giftmessage/inline.phtml
```

(as mentioned here: [How to remove the 2 checkboxes from the Gift Messages on Order Level?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/67633/how-to-remove-the-2-checkboxes-from-the-gift-messages-on-order-level) )

I found the code mentioned by Anil Suthar in the answer below in the:

`/public_html/skin/frontend/smartwave/porto/css/custom.css` file.

I uploaded the same file to the same directory on Magento 1.9.4 but it does not work! **Any ideas?**

Comment: Is it OK for you, if you do this by  just  CSS, like: `display:block !important` ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't mind doing it any which way that works...the only thing is - I don't know much about CSS - would I just add that code to....where exactly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with some CSS. Add following CSS to any `.css` file (that is available in checkout page).

```
.gift-messages p.control {
  display: none;
}
#allow-gift-message-container.gift-messages-form {
  display: block !important;
}
#allow-gift-message-container.gift-messages-form p {
  display: none;
}
#allow-gift-messages-for-order-container.allow-gift-messages-for-order-container {
  display: block !important;
}
```

You can add/edit/remove css that suites your requirements. Also can edit `.phtml` that contains Gift Message forms, here `/app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/giftmessage/inline.phtml`

Comment: I am trying to set this up on Magento 1.9.4 but I don't have any luck. I have modified both the /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/giftmessage/inline.phtml file as well as I found your code (right above here) in the  /public_html/skin/frontend/smartwave/porto/css/custom.css file. I uploaded the same file to the same directory on Magento 1.9.4 but it does not work! Any ideas?